# What type of array should I be using?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a project for a class and I'm not sure what type of array I should be using for this program. I have to make a stock market program where the user buys, sells and views stock listings and checks their account balance. There are two text files that contain the following data:

```
Leon1111            5000.00
Wise2222            10000.00
Woo3333             3000.00
White4444           7000.00
Head5555            4000.00
```

and

```
Apple                  AAPL             450.00
Boeing                 BA               75.50
Intel                  INTC             22.30
Rambus                 RMBS             5.55
Sirius                 SIRI             3.15
Skyworks               SWKS             25.35
Xilinx                 XLNX             36.80
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream outStream;
    int option;

    do
    {
        cout << "1) Check Stock Listings " << endl;
        cout << "2) Buy Stock " << endl;
        cout << "3) Sell Stock" << endl;
        cout << "4) Check Account Balance " << endl;
        cout << "5) Quit " << endl << endl;
        cout << "Please select an option : ";
        cin >> option;
        cout << endl;

        if (option == 1)
        {
            fstream CompaniesFile;
            CompaniesFile.open("Companies.txt");
            if (CompaniesFile.is_open())
            {
                string s;
                while (getline(CompaniesFile, s, '\n'))
                {
                    cout << s << endl;
                }
            }
            CompaniesFile.close();
        }

        else if (option == 2)
        {

        }

        else if (option == 3)
        {

        }

        else if (option == 4)
        {
            fstream AccountFile;
            AccountFile.open("Account.txt");
            if (AccountFile.is_open())
            {
                string t;
                while (getline(AccountFile, t))
                {

                    cout << t << endl;
                }
            }
            AccountFile.close();
        }

        else if (option == 5)
        {
            cout << "Program Terminated. Have a nice day!" << endl << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Option entered" << endl;
        }
    }
    while (option != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good you don't want us to do it for you but you need to be more specific in your question. What are you trying to store in the array? How will it be used?

Comment: why not create a struct and then make an array of the struct

Comment: You can see the options I have (1-5) in the beginning of my do-while loop. If Leon1111 buys 1 stock in Apple, it must subtract 450.00 from his account and store that new value so that when he checks his account it will show his new balance. Also, it must save to a third file showing his account ID (1111), whether he bought or sold, the stock symbol (AAPL), and how many shares.

Comment: Thank you Frederick888, this is kind of what I was thinking. Again, I am new so I wasn't sure whether I needed some type of pointer array, 3D array, or struct

Comment: -1: What was the question? How does the code relate to the question-title? What do the columns mean in the data? How do the tables relate to each other?

Comment: Per @Valentin's comment I voted to close as off-topic, since there isn't a real question here.

Comment: @Kay Why `int64_t`?  Does the type really have to have exactly 64 bits?  `long long` seems more indicated.  (Actually, what is indicated is a special `Currency` class.  Which may use `long long` internally, but will handle all of the issues.)

Answer (score 1):

```
class cCompany
{
  std::string myName;
  std::string mySymbol;
  double myPrice;

public:
  cCompany(  const std::string& name,
             const std::string& symbol,
             double price )
  : myName( name ), mySymbol( symbol ), myPrice( price )
  {}
};

std::vector< cCompany > vCompany;

class cAccount
{
  std::string myName
  double myBalance;
public:
  cAccount( const std:string& name, double balance )
  : myName( name ), myBalance( balance )
{}
};

std:vector< cAccount > vAccount;

...

std::string name;
std::string symbol;
double price;
while ( CompaniesFile.good() )
{

    CompaniesFile >> name;
    CompaniesFile >> symbol;
    CompaniesFile >> price;
    vCompany.push_back( cCompany( name, symbol, price ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this should give me some direction

Comment: Even Microsoft doesn't use Hungarian notation anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to probably need a bit more than name and balance for an account holder, so if I had my druthers I would use a vector (or map) of a class for account holders. The account holder class would hold name, balance, and then a vector (or even better a map) of shares that the person holds and the number of shares. Something like:

```
class AccountHolder{
private:
     std::string name_;
     long long int balance_;  //balance in cents

     //to allow for something like buy("AAPL", 100);
     //  to be implemented as:
     //     void buy(std::string symbol, long int shares)
     //     {
     //         long int price = shares * sharePrice[symbol];
     //         if (balance_ >= price)
     //         {
     //             balance_ -= price;
     //             holdings_[symbol] += shares;
     //         } else
     //             throw(INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS);
     //     }
     std::map<std::string, long long int> holdings_;

public:
     ...
};
```

For shares, I would use a map since you only need to know their name (and/or symbol) and the price. Maybe you can have the key be the symbol, and then the value to be price, and another map for symbol and full name. This way you can easily find the share prices: all you need to do is

```
std::cout << "price of a single share from " << fullName["AAPL"]
          << " is: " << sharePrice["AAPL"] << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your application more OO-like (Object Oriented). My suggestion is first you can create some data structures:

```
struct user { string name; double balance; }
struct stock { string name; double price; }
struct stockBought { string userName; string stockName; int share; }
```

then use something to save your data, for example,

```
list<user> users;
list<stock> stocks;
list<stockBought> stockBought;
```

then you should have a function to read from the two files

```
readUsersFromFile(users, fUsersFile);
readStocksFromFile(stocks, fStockFile);
```

then you should have a function to update the list

```
update(users, 3, 1, 4000.0);  //update the users list: 3rd user, 1st column (5000.0 => 4000.0)
add(stockBought, "Leon1111", "AAPL", 1); //leon bought 1 share of AAPL
```

then you have to implement all the functions needed for the 5 options. Add more utility functions/classes as you move on.

Once you finish the 1st version. you can polish your code to make it run faster (adding index etc) or look better (better class).